# Not overlapping cluster popups with FeaturePopups control

Tags: openlayers-2, clustering, popup

[FeaturePopups control](http://jorix.github.com/OL-FeaturePopups/examples/feature-popups.html) resolve the problem of cluster popups, but there is a small design problem in my opinion: the event popup have the same anchor as the cluster popup and they partial or total overlap.

Is it possible to anchor the second (event) popup on the link on first (cluster) popup?

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can have two solutions:

- allow second popups will have a close box:

`var fpControl = new OpenLayers.Control.FeaturePopups({
     popupListItemOptions: {closeBox: true},
     ...`

- close the list popup when it shows the second popup:

`var fpControl = new OpenLayers.Control.FeaturePopups({
     popupListItemOptions: {relatedToClear: ['list', 'single']},
     ...`